# iOS Control Sound Volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm playing sounds like this:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
..
..
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
   pathForResource:@"ClickSound" ofType:@"wav"];    

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

It seems to take it's volume from 'Ringer', But when I use the physical volume button it control the 'Volume' (so I can 'Mute' the volume - but I still hear the sound).

I want to control the right volume and I don't want it to play when it's muted (BTW - when I use the mute toggle it works, and I don't hear the sound).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AudioServicesCreateSystemSound applies only to the ringer volume.

You can use AVAudioPlayer for this.
Here is some sample code:

```
AVAudioPlayer *buttonClick=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"buttonClick"] ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];
[buttonClick prepareToPlay];
[buttonClick play];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for you to control the volume in code.  You can provide a UI control to let the user change the volume.

Audio is managed by categories, and behavior differs with respect to respecting the hardware settings.

The `Ambient` category will honor the mute switch; the others won't.

No category allows you to determine the position of the mute switch.

Comment: I want to control the sound by the physical controllers, they control the 'Volume' but the sound of my game is always the same. In other words - I want the 'Volume' to control the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() function and not the 'Ringer'. @Avi

Comment: What you want and what you get are different things. It would be an awful user experience if any stupid app could set the volume any way it wants, with possibly different controls that I have to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should register for Volume button's Call backs using below code,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
     name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
     object:nil];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume =
    [[[notification userInfo]
      objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
     floatValue];
}
```

Hope it will helps .
Happy coding :)